# How to get specific date and time timestamp for different timezone java?

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, timezone

In my case i have two string one contains (YYYY-MM-DD) in this format and another string contain (HH:MM:SS) in this format. I need to convert this to PST timestamp with date and time mentioned in those String, without `TimeZone.setDefault()` method. My server timezone is Coordinated Universal Time.

Comment: append two strings, create `DateTimeFormatter` and get `LocalDateTime`according to this formatter

Comment: You have a date and a time. But what is the original zone? Do you mean that the date and time should always be considered PST? (BTW, don't use three-letter acronyms. Use Region/City format). Or do you want to convert to PST from some other zone?

Comment: Original timezone was coordinated universal time. Only respective date along with  time has to be converted into (Pacific standard Time ) timestamp

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

```
    String dateStringUtc = "2019-11-30";
    String timeStringUtc = "21:00:45";

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateStringUtc);
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeStringUtc);
    ZonedDateTime pstDateTime = date.atTime(time)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
    System.out.println("Timestamp in Los Angeles time zone: " + pstDateTime);
```

Output from the snippet is:

> Timestamp in Los Angeles time zone:
>   2019-11-30T13:00:45-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]

I am exploiting the fact that each of your strings is in ISO 8601 format. The classes of java.time, the modern Java date and time API, parse ISO 8601 format as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter.

I assumed that by PST you meant Pacific Time (standard or daylight time according to the time of year). I couldn’t believe you wanted Pacific Standard Time all year. If you meant Philippine Standard Time, use Asia/Manila. If you intended Pitcairn Standard Time, specify Pacific/Pitcairn.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)